# Group call conference in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cordova, webrtc

Is it possible to create group call conference using Swift? I just got requirement from my client to develop using native app. I already searched the web, but so far it supports only for Phonegap using WebRTC.

https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 7, Apple introduced Multipeer Connectivity with `NSOutputStream` and `NSInputStream` which facilitate the transmission of audio to multiple listeners. Check out [Streaming Audio to Multiple Listeners via iOS's Multipeer Connectivity](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity) which goes into depth about this topic.

Comment: is it using phone number or server?

Comment: This is encoding audio data to mp3 or aac and relaying it to a server. If you want to arrange a conference call with phone numbers, try UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "tel://1234567890")) for multiple clients

Comment: quite nice explanation. BTW, thanks!!